# Can stanford ner tagger process hindi or nepali language?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I would like to train a ner model using **stanford-ner.jar** CRFClassifier for Nepali or Hindi language. Can I simply use the java command line mentioned in the [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#a)

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you supply training data you can produce a new model.  Note that when running the NER system, you will need to tokenize the text in the same way it was tokenized for the training process.

There is some more info about training NER models here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html